# Continuity of multiplicative  character

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lo.logic, harmonic-analysis, semigroups-and-monoids, stone-cech-compactification

Let $G$ be a discrete group and $\beta (G)$ denote the Stone-Cech compactification of $G$, a right topological semigroup. By a multiplicative character, I mean a mapping that preserves multiplication but it is not necessarily continuous.

1- Is there any example of a multiplicative character $\gamma :\beta (G)\to \mathbb{T}$ that is not continuos?

2- Is there any concrete example of a multiplicative character $\gamma :\beta (G)\to \mathbb{T}$? I know how to build abstract examples but don't know of any concrete example.

Comment: Does "multiplicative linear functional" mean "homomorphism"?

Comment: What do you mean by "linear"? Where is the vector space structure?

Comment: Sorry. I should have said "character".

Comment: Anyway I don't even think $\beta G$ is a semigroup in general. How do you define the product in $\beta {\bf Z}$?

Comment: @ Nik: For any discrete semigroup $(S,.)$, the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta (S)$ of $S$ admits an extension of the operation so that $(\beta S,.)$ is a compact right topological semigroup (meaning right multiplication remains continuous). A good source of information is the book by N.Hindman and D.Struass: 
http://books.google.ca/books?id=mjmPHAhJkmYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=semigroup+stone+cech&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Vj8AUaaSGqiuiQLsh4HACw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=semigroup%20stone%20cech&f=false

Comment: @Nik: Arens products on 2nd dual of $\ell^1({\bf Z})$ ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "concrete" in (2)?  There are of course many examples of multiplicative characters in, e.g., the case $G = \mathbb{Z}$.  The characters of $\mathbb{Z}$ are just the maps of the form $k\mapsto z^k$, where $z\in\mathbb{T}$; these extend (by the universal property of $\beta\mathbb{Z}$) to continuous functions $\beta\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{T}$, and it's easy to check that these extensions are multiplicative.

But if you're looking for something more constructive, you would be out of luck, since you need some Choice to make a nonprincipal ultrafilter.

Comment: @ Paul: Sure, but I want it to be non-continuous on the Stone-Cech compactification.